# Android Exoplayer DownloadTracker: Failed to fetch offline DRM license

Tags: android, exoplayer, offline-caching, exoplayer2.x, android-video-player

I need to play DRM-protected content offline.

However, after building the DRM session, the following error is thrown:

Failed to fetch offline DRM license
com.google.android.exoplayer2.drm.DrmSession$DrmSessionException:
com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.HttpDataSource$InvalidResponseCodeException: Response code: 403
at com.google.android.exoplayer2.drm.DefaultDrmSession.onError(DefaultDrmSession.java:524)
at com.google.android.exoplayer2.drm.DefaultDrmSession.onKeysError(DefaultDrmSession.java:519)
at com.google.android.exoplayer2.drm.DefaultDrmSession.onKeyResponse(DefaultDrmSession.java:482)
at com.google.android.exoplayer2.drm.DefaultDrmSession.access$100(DefaultDrmSession.java:58)
at com.google.android.exoplayer2.drm.DefaultDrmSession$ResponseHandler.handleMessage(DefaultDrmSession.java:563)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:65)
Caused by: com.google.android.exoplayer2.drm.MediaDrmCallbackException: com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.HttpDataSource$InvalidResponseCodeException: Response code: 403
at com.google.android.exoplayer2.drm.HttpMediaDrmCallback.executePost(HttpMediaDrmCallback.java:194)
at com.google.android.exoplayer2.drm.HttpMediaDrmCallback.executeKeyRequest(HttpMediaDrmCallback.java:153)
at com.google.android.exoplayer2.drm.DefaultDrmSession$RequestHandler.handleMessage(DefaultDrmSession.java:602)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:65) 
Caused by: com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.HttpDataSource$InvalidResponseCodeException: Response code: 403
at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ext.cronet.CronetDataSource.open(CronetDataSource.java:588)
at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.StatsDataSource.open(StatsDataSource.java:84)
at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DataSourceInputStream.checkOpened(DataSourceInputStream.java:101)
at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DataSourceInputStream.read(DataSourceInputStream.java:81)
at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DataSourceInputStream.read(DataSourceInputStream.java:75)
at com.google.android.exoplayer2.util.Util.toByteArray(Util.java:174)
at com.google.android.exoplayer2.drm.HttpMediaDrmCallback.executePost(HttpMediaDrmCallback.java:177)
at com.google.android.exoplayer2.drm.HttpMediaDrmCallback.executeKeyRequest(HttpMediaDrmCallback.java:153) 
at com.google.android.exoplayer2.drm.DefaultDrmSession$RequestHandler.handleMessage(DefaultDrmSession.java:602) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:65)

Answer (score 0):

This error is showing that the DRM server responded with a 403 response.

This response code means:

> 6.5.3.  403 Forbidden
>
> The 403 (Forbidden) status code indicates that the server understood
> the request but refuses to authorize it.  A server that wishes to
> make public why the request has been forbidden can describe that
> reason in the response payload (if any).

(https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#page-59)

So, your request is being sent to the DRM server correctly and the DRM server understand it, but it not sending you a license in response. Generally, a DRM sever won't provide much detail why it refuses a request, to try to minimise info gathering attacks.

The usual reasons for DRM server 403 response are either because there is missing authentication information in the request, or the authentication info included does not allow that user view that particular content.

The best approach at this point is usually to speak to whoever your DRM server provider is and share with them the detailed request and response.